# AForge.NET - name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, aforge

I want to make an application which activates the webcam and detects movement. So far I can turn ON and OFF the application. Now I'm trying to implement motion detector. The problem is - *'bitmap' does not exist in the current context.* The method from which it originates is private. I tried with public, but still. And somehow Form1 is able to use it.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Vision.Motion;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // create motion detector
        MotionDetector detector = new MotionDetector(new SimpleBackgroundModelingDetector(), new MotionAreaHighlighting());

        public VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = null;
        public FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // enumerate video devices
            videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

            // create video source
            videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);

            // set NewFrame event handler
            videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);

            // continuously feed video frames to motion detector
            while (true)
            {
                // process new video frame and check motion level
                if (detector.ProcessFrame(bitmap) > 0.02) << // PROBLEM
                {
                    // ring alarm or do something else
                }
            }

            // start the video source
            videoSource.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            videoSource.Stop();
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
        }

        // Method:
        private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // get new frame
            Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;
            // process the frame

            // Put image in picture box
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)bitmap.Clone();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You declared bitmap in video_NewFrame, how is it going to be accessible to anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this code:

```
while (true)
{
    // process new video frame and check motion level
    if (detector.ProcessFrame(bitmap) > 0.02) << // PROBLEM
    {
        // ring alarm or do something else
    }
}
```

And change the event code to this:

```
// Method:
private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // get new frame
    Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;
    // process the frame

    // Put image in picture box
    pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)bitmap.Clone();

    if (detector.ProcessFrame(bitmap) > 0.02) << // PROBLEM
    {
        // ring alarm or do something else
    }
}
```

It looks like you reused some code but put it in the wrong place.

Don't take me wrong but putting a while loop inside `button1_Click` is an indication that you are just starting with c#. Aforge.net is quite advanced stuff, I recommend you keep your programs simple as much as possible for now - motion detector may be too big of a chunk.

Comment: You got me. I'm still on basics level and console stuff with C#. But I have an assignment to make on Computer Vision and I thought I'd try and make an application that can detect motion. Something simple (or so I thought).
 I don't have much experience with windows forms.

Comment: I sure am embarrassed. I'm really learning C#.
The fast replies and the help are appreciated. :) Thank you!

Comment: No problems, that's what StackOverflow is for. I'm glad I could help :).